# Meaning of $\vee$ notation after an integral

Tags: soft-question, notation

I have an equation with the $\vee$ notation that I've not come across before.

$$ \tilde f(\omega, t) = e^{-2\pi i\omega t}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{2\pi i v t} \, \bar{g}(v - \omega) \, \hat f(v) \, dv$$

$$ = e^{-2\pi i\omega t} \left(\bar{g}(v - \omega)\, \hat f(v)\right)^{\vee} \, (t).$$

Could anyone suggest what this means? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the inverse Fourier transform of the function $v\mapsto\bar{g}(v-\omega)\hat{f}(v)$ (the ${}^\vee$ is supposed to be an "inverted $\hat{\phantom{a}}$").